# Reduce number of bullets in navigation bar

Tags: beamer, presentations, navigation, bullets

I'm using the Warsaw theme in my presentation, I want to remove bullets that concern TOC in the navigation bar.

For example here in the Dynamic model section, the two first bullets concern the TOC for the section and subsection that I want to remove (Because I have a lot of slides and the bullets will stick together, and I want to reduce the number of bullets)
[image: For example here in Dynamic model section the two first bullets concern the TOC for section and subsection I want to remove]

This is the code:

```
 \documentclass[serif,12pt,aspectratio=169,compress,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usetheme{Warsaw} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\useoutertheme[subsection= false]{miniframes}

\AtBeginSection[ ]
{
\begin{frame}[plain]{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideallsubsections]
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
\end{frame}
}

\AtBeginSubsection[ ]
{
\begin{frame}[plain]{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/hide,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,subsubsectionstyle=hide]%hideallsubsections]
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
\end{frame}
}

\AtBeginSubsubsection[ ]
{
\begin{frame}[plain]{Outline}
\usebeamercolor{subsection in toc shaded}%
\tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/hide%
,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,subsubsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide]
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
\end{frame}
}
\begin{document}
\section{Dynamic Model}
\subsection{Assumptions}
\begin{frame}

\end{frame}
\subsection{Coordinate systems}
\begin{frame}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix it, please

Comment: Can you please make a compilable minimal reproducible example instead of a code fragments which we can't compile on its own?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Ok, I changed the code

Comment: Thanks! This made answering much easier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can temporarily switch the miniframes off like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,aspectratio=169,compress,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\useoutertheme[subsection= false]{miniframes}

\makeatletter
\let\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson=\beamer@writeslidentry%
\def\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff{%
  \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}% does not happen normally
  {%else
    % removed \addtocontents commands
    \clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
  }
}
\newcommand*{\miniframeson}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframeson}
\newcommand*{\miniframesoff}{\let\beamer@writeslidentry=\beamer@writeslidentry@miniframesoff}
\makeatother

\AtBeginSection[ ]
{
\miniframesoff
\begin{frame}[plain]{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideallsubsections]
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
\end{frame}
\miniframeson
}

\AtBeginSubsection[ ]
{
\miniframesoff
\begin{frame}[plain]{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/hide,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,subsubsectionstyle=hide]%hideallsubsections]
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
\end{frame}
\miniframeson
}

\AtBeginSubsubsection[ ]
{
\miniframesoff
\begin{frame}[plain]{Outline}
\usebeamercolor{subsection in toc shaded}%
\tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/hide%
,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,subsubsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide]
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
\end{frame}
\miniframeson
}
\begin{document}
\section{Dynamic Model}
\subsection{Assumptions}
\begin{frame}
one frame
\end{frame}
\subsection{Coordinate systems}
\begin{frame}
another frame
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(please note that the `serif` class option is obsolete, you should use `\usefonttheme{serif}` instead)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response, it solved my problem

Comment: @DENA11 You're welcome!