Customizing Title Bullets in the Frankfurt Theme to 2 or 3 rows
I am using the Frankfurt theme in Beamer and I want to customize the title bullets. Currently, they appear in a single row, but I would like to know if it is possible to set them to appear in 2 or 3 rows.
Some Screenshots:
As is:

To be:

This feature can be very helpful for lengthy PDF's.
Sample code:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\section{Section2}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\end{document}


You could use the miniframes outer theme. Its layout is similar, but it allows splitting the miniframes into multiple lines by using subsections:
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}

\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\section{Section2}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} \end{frame}
\end{document}



I cannot use both this solution and  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675105/reduce-number-of-bullets-in-navigation-bar because the other solution doesnt work without the compress option \documentclass[compress]{beamer}
Any suggestion?

possible soltion: Is it possible to use \usetheme{Frankfurt} inside this answer?

The Frankfurt theme forces the compress option, which disallows multiple lines. Even if one forcefully disables the compress option after loading the Frankfurt theme, the size of the colour gradients in the  background is hard coded and won't adjust to multiple lines of miniframes.

So i need to ask another question to have both compress option and the above solution together?

No, you don't want compression if you want the miniframes over multiple lines.
